# Embedded Event Lists code taking up full page

Tags: javascript, eventbrite

When I embed the code provided by EventBrite to show the events that I have organized on my site, the page loads normally but then the JavaScript expands to take up the whole page.

How do I stop this from happening? I have put in my organizer ID and API key. Below is the example code provided:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://evbdn.eventbrite.com/s3-s3/static/js/platform/Eventbrite.jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  Eventbrite({'app_key': $APP_KEY}, function(eb){
    eb.organizer_list_events( {'id': 561037966, 'statuses': "live,started"}, function( response ){
      document.write(eb.utils.eventList( response, eb.utils.eventListRow ));
    });
  });
});​
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the Evenbrite javascript API.  The layout is determined by the markup and css styling of your page.  The `eventList` method returns HTML, so you can put that into a specific element and style it appropriately.  For example:

```
<head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      Eventbrite({'app_key': $APP_KEY}, function(eb){
        eb.organizer_list_events( {'id': 561037966, 'statuses': "live,started"}, function( response ){
          var event_list_html = eb.utils.eventList( response, eb.utils.eventListRow );
          $("#event-list").html(event_list_html);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  <style>
    #event-list {
      width: 400px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }   
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="event-list"></div>
</body>
```